# Is there an easy way to flatten an array of objects while making an array of the one column that would be different?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq

I have an array of objects similar to this:

```
 class StateVisitor
 {
     string FirstName { get; set; }
     string LastName { get; set; }
     string StateViseted { get; set; }
 }
    
 StateVisitor[] StateVisitors = {
     new() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith", StateViseted = "AL" },
     new() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith", StateViseted = "AK" },
     new() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Jones", StateViseted = "AL" },
     new() { FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Smith", StateViseted = "UT" }
  }
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
 class VisitorsWithCombinedStates {
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string[] StatesVisetedArray { get; set; }
}

 VisitorsWithCombinedStates[] visitorsWithCombinedStates = StateVisitors... /* Linq magic? */

 visitorsWithCombinedStates.ForEach(v 
     => Console.WriteLine($"{v.FirstName} {v.LastName} visited {string.Join(", ",v.StatesVisitedArray)}"));

        // "Bob Smith visited AL, AK"
        // "Bob Jones visited AL"
        // "Sam Smith visited UT"
```

Is there an easy way, in C# (probably with LINQ) to flatten that first array into the second array, where it makes an array of the states visited?

Comment: You've tagged this `C#`, `arrays`, `.NET`, and `Linq` and didn't include a single one of them in your question. The example is of a table or grid, not an array; note that arrays do not have “columns”. Post code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @DourHighArch -- Sorry about that; I was writing this entirely in the WYSIWYG editor, and not in my IDE, so I wanted to save characters.  I've updated it.

Comment: How does visitorsWithCombinedStates look like? Can you share example,,?

Comment: @Chetan I added a class to explain the structure  of `visitorsWithCombinedStates`

Comment: `visitorsWithCombinedStates.ForEach(v 
     => Console.WriteLine($"{v.FirstName} {v.LastName} visited {string.Join(", ",v.StatesVisitedArray)}");`

Comment: @Chetan -- I knew someone was gonna catch that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `GroupBy` then projecting the groups into your new class:

```
var visitorsWithCombinedStates = StateVisitors.GroupBy(sv => new { sv.FirstName, sv.LastName }, sv => sv.StateVisited)
                                              .Select(svg => new VisitorsWithCombinedStates {
                                                  FirstName = svg.Key.FirstName,
                                                  LastName = svg.Key.LastName,
                                                  StatesVisitedArray = svg.ToArray()
                                              })
                                              .ToArray();
```

NOTE: Corrected spelling of visited

Answer (score 2):

You want to group your items by a combination of first and last name and project the result of the grouping as just the state visited

```
var groups = stateVisitors.GroupBy(sv => new
    {
        sv.FirstName,
        sv.LastName,
    },
    sv => sv.StateVisited );
```

Output:

```
foreach(var g in groups)
{
    // g.Key.FirstName
    // g.Key.LastName
    // g is IEnumerable<string> of visited states
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example, to fill your **VisitorsWithCombinedStates** class:

```
VisitorsWithCombinedStates[] visitorsWithCombinedStates = StateVisitors.GroupBy(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName},x => x.StateViseted)
.Select(x => new VisitorsWithCombinedStates { FirstName = x.Key.FirstName, LastName = x.Key.LastName, StatesVisetedArray = x.ToArray() }).ToArray();
```